# How to run macros on custom selected cells on google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Totally new to google-sheets, so pardon me if it's a noob question or the wrong way of achieving the desired task.
I am trying to use macros to record steps to come to a value. Steps are: `select two columns->convert to time->subtract these two columns to get time difference-> sum time difference to get total time`. My time data is like this:

```
 9:48:00 AM 10:02:00 AM
10:21:00 AM 10:34:00 AM
10:39:00 AM 10:49:00 AM
11:05:00 AM 11:24:00 AM
11:35:00 AM 11:54:00 AM
12:01:00 PM 12:15:00 PM
12:16:00 PM 12:40:00 PM
```

I initially recorded macro on 10 cells. My initial assumption was that I could also use it on the cells that I select anywhere on the sheet.
But it's certainly not working. A little guide would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend to [edit] your question and include what you hava tried, because [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Comment: AS @Pᴇʜ mentioned it'd be helpful to have a public Spreadsheet in order to know what you have tried so far.

Comment: @JoseVasquez No, actually providing files is not recommended. They may disappear after a while and the question gets completely useless for future readers. Instead (according [ask]) everything that is needed to understand and answer the question needs to be in the question itself. So the code must be copied as code block into the question, screenshots of sheets might help too. No links to files!

Comment: In effect, the forum does recommend that `Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time` but it's not mandatory whereas it says `DO NOT post images of code`, I agree files can disappear after some time. Usually when it comes to Google Sheets it's necessary to have a visual summary (not code) so the community can better understand the question.